# How to talk to each other in minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When playing minecraft on LAN I have tried to setup microphone and speakers. I'm not able to use microphone and speakers to make my kids talk to each other. They keep yelling through the house: "I'm here, come help me" "Wow, did you see that" etc etc. How do I setup the microphone in minecraft so they can talk to each other?

Comment: Does Minecraft actually have built in voice chat?

Comment: I'm not sure. I thought it had. Thanks for your comment. Now I can search online if it has or not.

Comment: I found this https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/glibys-voice-chat#:~:text=Gliby's%20Voice%20Chat%20adds%20the,combat%2C%20social%20and%20general%20interactions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Minecraft does not actually have a built in voice chat. If you're already running modded Minecraft and are familiar with setting up server mods, it does appear that there are mods that can *add* voice chat. However, the easiest thing to do is probably to get [Discord](https://discord.com/) set up on the two computer and set them up with a voice channel so they can talk that way.